# Failing transaction [not out of gas] but error during execution

Tags: contract-debugging, ropsten

My 2 assumptions of the problem:

- out of gas
- some failed `require` statement when calling mint

I don't see these 2 because I made sure to send more than enough gas and that `msg.value > priceForTokens` on the Ropsten network. Everything works fine with remix's JS VM.

Here's the [contract source](https://github.com/mohamedhayibor/ethervineAlpha/blob/master/contracts/MemeRecorder.sol#L44):

Here's one example of a failed transaction on [Ropsten](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xc1c987ed548241bc94a7058e0c4b5fed4be0654e46ef38caade3384ec60562ff).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you deployed the wrong contract. You deployed `MemeRecorder`, when I assume you meant to deploy `Meme`.

(I figured this out by [verifying the source code on Etherscan](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x63120c7978f51a726655efa704b730c3a89f79ae#code).)

Or perhaps you meant to deploy `MemeRecorder` but then are trying to call `mint()` on the wrong contract. It looks like `0x19a1a4a3e8f659d43b5353d21126b8bf846616ac` is an instance of `Meme` that was created via `addMeme()`. Maybe you meant to call `mint()` on that instead.

**EDIT**

I [verified the source code for `0x19a1a4a3e8f659d43b5353d21126b8bf846616ac`](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x19a1a4a3e8f659d43b5353d21126b8bf846616ac#code) for you too.

Comment: The order of execution I went with:

1. Deployed `MemeRecorder`
2. Used `addMeme` to create a new instance of `Meme`
3. Then on that new instance called `mint` which results in failure.

I'm still scratching my head why it's not working with this flow. Thanks for verifying the contract, I must get into the habit :)

Comment: You called `mint()` on `MemeRecorder` instead of on the new `Meme` instance.

Comment: No transactions have been sent to the `Meme` instance yet.

Comment: With `2.` I meant calling `mint()` on the new `Meme` instance not MemeRecorder. I tried with the correct flow both on Ropsten and Rinkeby. I also tried doing it the erroneous way by curiosity, I get some kindof rpc error alert from MyCrypto. I will take more stabs at it.

Comment: In the original question you asked, you linked to a transaction in which `mint()` was being called on `MemeRecorder`, which has no such function. It sounds like you're claiming otherwise, but perhaps I'm confused?

Answer (score 0):

Smarx: you are right. I was calling `mint()` on `MemeRecorder`.

The main problem: if the MemeRecorder factory doesn’t have a constructor it erroneously runs `addMeme` when I first instantiate `MemeRecorder`. Found that out with Remix’s debugger. Why? I have no idea, maybe it is mentioned somewhere deep in Solidity’s documentation.

The reason why I got myself and others deeply confused is that without the constructor, you would never see internal transactions either creating the `Meme` instance.

1. [0xAe2326591d730B4c5571580D799047c0FE51DF4E](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xae2326591d730b4c5571580d799047c0fe51df4e) (MemeRecorder)
2. [0x524B50F4F8B41DB9A5d9E17e5eE16fEa1095AAd6](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x524b50f4f8b41db9a5d9e17e5ee16fea1095aad6) (Meme instance)

The tricky thing is that when `addMeme()` is called on MemeRecorder, the new `Meme` instance is created via an [internal transaction](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xae2326591d730b4c5571580d799047c0fe51df4e#internaltx).

A successful buying (minting of tokens) is [here](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x49da435add56ed56dba0d0df3e3a2cdc9575754ecf9b271810b89cf536039e27).

- in all `Meme` contracts you would see internal transactions for when the change is getting sent back to buyer [internaltx](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x524b50f4f8b41db9a5d9e17e5ee16fea1095aad6#internaltx)

Thanks Smarx for helping me think about the issue, I’m an avid reader and fan of programtheblockchain.